# Graph Editor - Can I make proportional editing affect all the curves?

Tags: graph-editor

When I use the Proportional Editing option in Graph Editor it only affects curves that have nodes, selected by me. Why doesn't it affect all the curves? Is there a way to make it affect all the curves?

Essentially I want to select **just one node** on one curve and drag it with Proportional Edit on, affecting other nodes on **all** the curves. Can I achieve that?

Comment: Welcome, Alexander. If you hit Ctrl+K it will select all nodes at the same timeline position (collum nodes) of the selected node.

Comment: Thank you. But that's, again, not what I'm asking about. If I select those nodes, they will still be selected and moved as one.

Let me describe an example: If I have several objects that have an animated angle of rotation and I choose one object to edit that angle, but I want others change angle as well, but with "fall-off" based on how their angle differs from the object I selected. I would be able to do that with "proportional edit" option straight on. But only if it can affect curves that **don't have nodes selected**.

Comment: So? Does anyone have the answer? Or it's noone uses proportional edit in Graph Editor that much?

Comment: I think all the edits we do, we have to select a target first. What is not selected, is not influenced by the editing.

Comment: That's definitely NOT how Proportional Edit works in a 3D view. In Object Mode Proportional Edit affects all objects, regardless if they are selected or not. And in Edit Mode it affects all vertices unless you have a "connected" option turned on.

Answer (score -1):

Select all with the letter A.  There is the Box Select.

Comment: What exactly do I select? If I use A on the curve list, it just highlights all of them and does nothing. And if I use A on the main graph area, it just selects all the nodes - and thus I start to drag all of them at once, proportional editing or no. My question is - can I select just one node and drag it with Proportional Edit on, affecting other nodes on all the curves?

Comment: Perhaps your clarification is better placed in the original question.  You can up or down vote as you choose. I definitely understand your problem better now.